What is (and how to know) the relationship between network connections?
I have the following network set up:
PC------modem-----ISP
The modem is working in bridging mode so I need to create a broadband connection on my PC.
There are quite a few networking connections in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections:
"Ethernet 2" corresponds to the physical NIC on the PC, "Broadband Connection" corresponds to the broadband connection I created, and other connections are created by some VPN software.
Since these connections are all shown there, they seem to be in equal status. But they are actually not because some use the service of others so they must be on top of others. For example, the broadband connection must be using the physical NIC to transmit data to the modem so it seems to be on top of the  "Ethernet 2" connection. The connections created by VPN must be using the broadband connection(or the "Ethernet 2" connection?) to transmit data so they should be on top of the broadband connection(or the "Ethernet 2" connection?)
Using "route print -4", I can see which IP packet is sent to which network connection. The problem is how to know where to go next when the IP packets are going out of a network connection. For example, when the packets go out of a connection created by VPN, where do they go? Do they go to the broadband connection, or the "Ethernet 2" connection?
And I cannot see a data path between the broadband connection and the "Ethernet 2" connection. So, suppose I have two physical NICs each of which connects to a different modem provided by different ISP, how can I know which physical NIC to go when the data go out of the broadband connection? When I created the broadband connection, it did not ask me to choose a physical NIC(it only asked me for an account name/password gotten from an ISP).
